# Which is most appropriate place to compress responses when using a https reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to serve gziped data to clients. The data comes from a nginx reverse proxy that supports https, and behind it there is a http server.

I wonder what's the best place to gzip data, the https reverse proxy or the http server?

There is a `gzip_proxied` directive nginx that seems to cater for the former. But if I compress data in the reverse proxy, when the http server returns compressed data, will it be compressed twice?

Comment: if nginx can cache a GZIPed response from your origin server, surely that would mean less work overall.

Comment: Should all services behind nginx have GZIPed responses? In my setup, the nginx reverse proxy does all transport related work, like gzip and tls-encryption while the servers behind nginx are plain http servers, which should all have those things provided by nginx. If it is the same for you, you probably should use Nginx for it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I enabled gzip in the reverse proxy.